# Unresolved reference: resources

Tags: android, kotlin

I am getting unresolved reference: resources error. Looked at the example here (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource : val array: Array = resources.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array), I think I am using the right syntax. Then why getting error?

```
import com.example.wordadapter.R

class DataSource {

companion object{

    val xList: List<String> = resources.getStringArray(R.array.String_List).toList()
    
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have a valid array named String_List in your resources directory?

Comment: Yes. I have an array in values, <string-array name="String_List">.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`resources` is not a global property, it's a method that belongs to the `Context` type (see [`Context.getResources`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getResources()). You need a reference to `Context` to be able to access `resources`, e.g.:

```
import com.example.wordadapter.R

class DataSource {

companion object{

    fun xList(context: Context): List<String> = context.resources.getStringArray(R.array.String_List).toList()
    
}
```

Comment: Egor, thanks! It did work. However, I am having issue in accessing the xList. As I type, val details  = DataSource.xList(this), I get an error. Type mismatch:  Context was expected

Comment: What's `this` pointing to in your invocation? Are you calling `DataSource.xList(this)` from an `Activity`?

Comment: I am not calling from an Activity. My intent is to get the reference of the xList, created under the companion object in a method getItemCount() : Int

Comment: You need to pass an instance of `Context` to `xList`.

Comment: I tried to create an instance of Context. Getting message that it is an abstract class

Comment: Don't create an instance of `Context` manually. Pass an instance of `Activity`, or `Service`, or something else that implements `Context` that you have in scope.

Comment: I made it work Egor. Thanks for your valuable input! I am yet to learn more about Context class.

Comment: That's good to hear! Please accept my answer if you found it helpful.